# tried to get json formatter from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I tried to get a formatter json from mysql, but I dont know how can get it.

```
$query = 'SELECT data1,data2,data3,data4 FROM database';
$dbquery = mysql_query($query);
$geojson = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbquery)) {
    $feature = array('loc' => $row['data1'],$row['data2'],'title' => $row['data3'], $row['data4']);
    array_push($geojson,$feature);
};

echo json_encode($geojson);
```

This outputs:

```
[{"loc":data1,"0":data2,"title":"data3","1":"data4"},
{"loc":data1,"0":data2,"title":"data3","1":"data4"}]
```

I want this instead:

```
[{"loc":[data1,data2], "title":"data3 data4"},
{"loc":[data1,data2], "title":"data3 data4"}]
```

What should I change in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is not correct it should have been:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbquery)) {
    $feature = array('loc' => array(
                              $row['data1'],$row['data2']
                              ),
                     'title' => $row['data3'] .' '.$row['data4']
                );
    array_push($geojson,$feature);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query and see if it gives you the output that you need

```
        SELECT
    CONCAT('[', 
            GROUP_CONCAT('
                  CONCAT('{"loc": [', data1, data2, '], ')
                , CONCAT('"title": "', data3, data4 ,'"}')
                )
, ']')
        FROM database
```

you can also do something like this

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(data1,data2) AS loc
, CONCAT(data3,data4) as title 
FROM database';
```

Then in PHP you can do this

```
$feature = array(array('loc'=> $row['loc'],
                 'title' => $row['title']));
echo json_encode($feature);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your $feature line like this:

```
$feature = array('loc' => array($row['data1'], $row['data2']),'title' => $row['data3'].' '.$row['data4']);
```

That will result in a json blob like the following, for each line:

> {"loc":["data1","data2"],"title":"data3 data4"}

**Explanation**

- loc: You want an array. So you have do define it with array() in PHP. If you want to cast the value to numbers, just typecast them if needed:

  array((float)$row['data1'], (float)$row['data2'])
- title: Just concatenate the two strings with dots and a space in-between.